# How to apply different style sheets based on the language?

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I am using [Angular Internationalization (i18n)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview) to translate a website from English to Arabic and vice versa. Since Arabic is an RTL language and English is an LTR language, I need to load different stylesheets depending on the locale. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any javascript, you could just use the attribute selector and encapuslate your styling under the scss file.

Anything that you wan't different for RTL you can apply after

```html
<p>Left to right</p>
<p dir="rtl">Right to left</p>
```

```css
p {
  color: red
}

p[dir="rtl"] {
  color: blue
}
```

Comment: I am currently using scss to style the website, so is it possible to wrap a whole separate stylesheet with the encapsulation instead of going to each selector one by one and adding [dir="rtl"]?. Also how does importing other stylesheets like bootstrap work in this scenario, as right now I am just simply importing bootstrap in the main scss file, but now I want to import rtl bootstrap if the language is RTL. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As long as the newly imported file is more specific, and is being imported after, it should work.